# Is there a way to select a text node using $('...').load('url selector')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to select a text node using $('...').load('url selector')? For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      $('<h2></h2>').appendTo('body').load('sample.xml rss channel item title:eq(0)');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code will select a `<title>` element, but because the browser doesn't recognize the `<title>` element, it displays nothing. Is there a way to select only the text inside the `<title>` element?

Note:

- I can't change the markup
- I know I can accomplish this using $.ajax() or other methods, I only want to know if it's possible to do the same thing using $.load()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I only want to know if it's possible to do the same thing using $.load()

No, because the syntax of `load` that you're relying on requires a CSS selector, which can only (in this case) target an *element*, not a text node.

As you've identified, you'll need to use `$.ajax` instead, with which you can trivially do what you're describing.

Comment: I figured as much. Do you have a reference for the CSS selector restriction? I wasn't able to find any documentation about this.

Comment: @threed: The [CSS selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and/or the [jQuery selectors API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). As far as I know, selectors can only target elements and pseudo-elements, not text nodes.